# Comparator doesn't remove number duplicates in TreeSet

Tags: java, arrays, integer, heap, comparator

I used a self-defined comparator to initialize treeset, making it a min-heap. It works fine to remove duplicates of small numbers such as 1, 2, 3. But when the numbers are large, duplicates remain in the treeset. Here's my code:

```
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
            Set<Integer> treeset = new TreeSet<>(new MyComparator()); 
            Integer[] array = new Integer[args.length]; 
            for (int i = 0 ; i < args.length ; i ++ ) { 
                    array[i] = Integer.valueOf(args[i]); 
                    treeset.add(array[i]); 
            } 
            for (Integer i : treeset) { 
                    System.out.print(i + " "); 
            } 
    } 

    public static class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer> { 
            @Override 
            public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) { 
                    if (i1 < i2) { 
                            return -1; 
                    } else if (i1 == i2) { 
                            return 0; 
                    } else { 
                            return 1; 
                    } 
            } 
    }
```

}

If I do java Test -2147483647 -2147483647 1 1, I get -2147483647 -2147483647 1. It seems like something is wrong with my comparator. I tried to debug. When -2147483647 and -2147483647 are compared, instead of returning 0, the compare method returns 1. Could someone please tell me why? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing instances of `Integer` with `==`, but `==`, applied to Objects, only compares if they are the same instance. In your case, `i1` and `i2` are two distinct instances despite having the same value.

Use the `equals` method to compare the content like in:

```
...
                } else if (i1,equals(i2)) { 
                        return 0; 
...
```

Why does it work with small numbers: small integers (-128 to 127 by default) are cached by the `Integer` class to avoid having to create a new Instance every time these are needed. Details: [Integer.valueOf(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-)

Answer (score 0):

When you create an `Integer`using `valueOf()` values from -128 to 127 are cached. This means for these range of values using the operator `==` for comparison will return `true` if both objects have the same integer value. For integer values less than -128 and greater than 127 that will not work, comparison will return `false` for objects having the same value. So use the `equals()` method for comparison instead of `==` if you want it to work correctly all the time.

Comment: awesome explanation! Thank you!